# Android: Call Another Activity from Activity

Tags: android, google-maps

hi how can I call another activity of the activity, which activity is showing google maps with input parameters from the previous activity ?

thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intents are the way to start other activites, and you invoke them by using `startActivity(theIntent)`. Example:

```
  Intent i = new Intent(this, TheOtherActivity.class);
  startActivity(i);
```

That will start one of your activities called "TheOtherActivity". The real question is, do you want to open *your own* map activity or the standard "Google Maps" activity? If you want the latter, the format is specified in [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html). Creating your own MapActivity I think is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: thanks for helping me dmon.
actually yeah i wanna use standard google maps activity. also i wanna use google google directions API

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Context.startActivity()` method to start a `MapActivity`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)

Comment: hi Jason,
could you give me some simple example?